# Consulta en tabla con indices agrupados vs no agrupados

Tags: sql, sql-server, indices

Colegas espero me puedan ayudar con la siguiente duda.

Tengo una tabla con indices en las columnas c1, c2,y c3, sobre esta tabla con miles de registros se le realiza la siguiente consulta (la consulta permite buscar por columnas en cualquier combinacion):

```sql
select T.c1, T.c2, T.c3
FROM TABLA_XYZ T 
WHERE 
    ( c1=@Parametro1 OR  Parametro1 IS NULL )
AND ( c2=@Parametro2 OR  Parametro2 IS NULL )
AND ( c3=@Parametro3 OR  Parametro3 IS NULL )
```

Cuando un parametro sea innecesario, se usa solamente NULL en el lugar del criterio de búsqueda y se deshabilita la condición a través de OR.

Mi duda es la siguiente: Para este caso la base de datos realiza un escanero entero de la tabla aunque exista un indice sobre cada columna? la consulta es optima en una tabla con indices agrupados o es mejor con indices no agrupados?

Comment: Entiendo que `Parametro1 IS NULL` en realidad debiera ser `@Parametro1 IS NULL`¿no?

Comment: Como respuesta general: "las decisiones del motor son inescrutables", es decir, es muy difícil predecir de antemano que camino va a elegir el motor, posiblemente, y acá estoy divagando, si el volumen de la tabla es relativamente pequeño, puede que el costo de un table scan sea relativamente económico y el motor elija esta estrategia

Answer (score 0):

Ese tipo de consultas en inglés les llaman *catch-all-queries* o consultas para atrapar todo (no sé si me recuerda al Señor de los anillos o a Pokemon). El problema con las mismas es que no pueden generar un plan óptimo para la consulta, sino que tienen que utilizar un plan seguro que permita ser reutilizado en futuros usos de la misma consulta.

Tomemos un ejemplo usando la base de datos AdventureWorks (en mi caso probé con AdventureWorks2016). Es un caso muy similar al que tienes, pero con algo que la gente puede probar más fácilmente.

```
DECLARE @ProductId         int      = 855,
        @TransactionType   nchar(1) = NULL,
        @Qty               int      = 2;

SELECT ProductID, TransactionID, Quantity
FROM Production.TransactionHistory
WHERE ( ProductID = @ProductID OR @ProductID IS NULL)
AND ( TransactionType = @TransactionType OR @TransactionType IS NULL)
AND ( Quantity = @Qty OR @Qty IS NULL);
```

Esta tabla tiene un índice en la columna ProductID, aunque no contiene las otras dos columnas. A pesar de que sería más eficiente hacer un `index seek` sobre la columna ProductId y luego un `Lookup` al índice clustered, no se puede utilizar esa opción por el riesgo de que en un futuro se pueda llegar a consultar con @ProductId como NULL y se tenga que realizar el lookup por todas las filas de la tabla. Por lo tanto, por seguridad siempre se hará un scan al índice clustered.

Para corregir eso, tenemos 2 opciones: usar `RECOMPILE` o SQL dinámico.

Usar **RECOMPILE**, es algo muy sencillo de hacer, ya que sólo se agrega un par de cosas a la consulta.

```
DECLARE @ProductId         int      = 855,
        @TransactionType   nchar(1) = NULL,
        @Qty               int      = 2;

SELECT ProductID, TransactionID, Quantity
FROM Production.TransactionHistory
WHERE ( ProductID = @ProductID OR @ProductID IS NULL)
AND ( TransactionType = @TransactionType OR @TransactionType IS NULL)
AND ( Quantity = @Qty OR @Qty IS NULL)
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Así se puede generar un nuevo plan cada vez que se ejecute la consulta y puede ser óptimo puesto que no se reutilizará. La desventaja es que la instrucción se tiene que compilar cada vez que se ejecute y eso puede tomar tiempo.

Usar **SQL Dinámico** es un poco más complicado pero tiene la ventaja de poder reutilizar planes. Esta es una buena opción cuando las variaciones son pocas y no se tenderá a complicar demasiado la consulta.

```
DECLARE @ProductId         int      = NULL,
        @TransactionType   nchar(1) = NULL,
        @Qty               int      = 2;

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX)

SET @SQL = N'
SELECT ProductID, TransactionType, Quantity
FROM Production.TransactionHistory ' + NCHAR(10)
+ STUFF(  CASE WHEN @ProductId IS NOT NULL       THEN N'AND ProductID = @ProductID ' + NCHAR(10)             ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN @TransactionType IS NOT NULL THEN N'AND TransactionType = @TransactionType ' + NCHAR(10) ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN @Qty IS NOT NULL             THEN N'AND Quantity = @Qty ' + NCHAR(10)                    ELSE '' END, 1, 3, 'WHERE') + ';'

--PRINT @SQL;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@ProductId int, @TransactionType nchar(1), @Qty int', @ProductId, @TransactionType, @Qty;
```

Ambas opciones permitirán hacer el `Index seek` y optimizarán la consulta, pero abusar de ellas puede ser un problema a largo plazo por el procesamiento adicional que implican. Por lo mismo, es recomendable evitar las *consultas-atrapa-todo* y dejarlas para casos muy específicos.

*Respuesta basada en el artículo [How to Confuse the SQL Server Query Optimizer](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-confuse-the-sql-server-query-optimizer/)*